# How do I correctly append elements to each other in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working through a school assignment in jQuery, and I'm having trouble understanding how to append objects to each other.  The assignment is to take the result of a GET query (An array of JSON objects) and use jQuery to display them on a webpage.

The objects look like this:

```
Object { 
    strDrink: "Afterglow", 
    strDrinkThumb: "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/vuquyv1468876052.jpg",  
    idDrink: "12560" }
```

I have the API part down.  My problem (I think) is with correctly creating and appending the HTML elements.  Using regular DOM selectors, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
let grid = document.createElement('div');
grid.classList.add('d-flex', 'flex-wrap', 'justify-content-center');
for (let i = 0; i < data.drinks.length; i++) {
    let card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('figure', 'col-3', 'mx-2', 'mb-3', 'border', 'border-4', 'border-white', 'rounded-0');
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.classList.add('card-img-top')
    img.src = data.drinks[i].strDrinkThumb;
    card.append(img);
    let drinkName = document.createElement('h5');
    drinkName.innerText = data.drinks[i].strDrink;
    drinkName.classList.add('py-5', 'figure', 'hover-class');
    card.append(drinkName);
    grid.append(card);
  }
  ("#results").append(grid);
```

I've created the grid element in jQuery like so:

```
$("#results").append('<div id="grid" class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center"></div>');
```

So far so good, as far as I can tell in the inspector.  Then if I loop through the elements like so:

```
for (var drink in data.drinks) {
    $("<div class='figure col-3 mx-2 mb-3 border border-4 border-white rounded-0'>Test</div>").appendTo("#grid");
```

I get the expected grid.  The problem I'm having is how to create the remaining elements using an id rather than a class, which I think would create a mess?  The objects have unique identifiers (name and id) that would work, I just don't know how to use those values in the HTML.  Or if there's a better way to do this, maybe? Also, can I create an element in jQuery and attach another element to that, rather than to something already in the html?

***Edit
After having gotten some sleep, I think I saw the obvious.  My issue now is accessing the data I need inside the HTML tags.  The code:

```
for (var drink in data.drinks) {     
    let card = $("<div class='figure col-3 mx-2 mb-3 border border-4 border-white rounded-0'></div>")
    let image = document.createElement('img');
    image.classList.add('card-img-top')
    image.src = drink.strDrinkThumb;
    let drinkName = document.createElement('h5');
    drinkName.innerText = drink.strDrink;
    drinkName.classList.add('py-5', 'figure', 'hover-class');
    $(image).append(drinkName);
    $(card).append(image);
    $(grid).append(card);
```

This works, except that the image and drinkName elements both appear as undefined in the webpage.  How do I get the code to pull the url and string values out of the drink object and use them properly?

Comment: What remaining elements are you trying to create? Please be specific about what HTML you are trying to produce.

Comment: Apologies.  My goal is to, for each element in the array, create a card element that contains the picture and the name of that drink(presumably each appended to the card), then append each card element to the grid element.  So:
```
let card = document.createElement('div');
let img = document.createElement('img');
let drinkName = document.createElement('h5');
card.append(img);
card.append(drinkName);
grid.append(card);
```
But it seems like I have to use unique identifiers in jQuery so that the same image doesn't get appended to every card?

Comment: You can use the `.id` property of any DOM element to give it an ID. But you haven't explained why you think you need to do that. If you are successfully creating and appending an `<h5>` with each drink's name, then the same should work with its image. What is wrong with the output you are producing?

Comment: Updated my question, sry for the lack of clarity in the original post.

Comment: What does `console.log(drink)` show when you put it in your loop? Also, does the console show any errors or warnings?

Comment: I fixed my issue.  All of my googling on how to create elements in jQuery discussed the matter in terms of appending elements to a parent, and I got it into my head that that was the only way to create an element in jQuery.  On discarding this assumption and simply declaring my new elements as I needed them, my problem unravelled!  Thank you all, though!